# Content on different files

Tags: jquery-mobile

It's possible to put the content of a navbar in a different file on Jquery Mobile? I have a navbar with a lot of options, right now the file is so big so I want to divide it on different files. Right now I have something like this:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div id="content1">
    <p>This is 1 (How to put this on another page?)</p>
    </div>

    <div id="content2">
    <p>This is 1 (How to put this on another page?)</p>
    </div>

    <div id="content3">
    <p>This is 1 (How to put this on another page?)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Its possible to place the content on a different file? I don't need to redirect to another page,what I need is to display the content in the same page, even when the content is in another file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [jQuery.mobile.loadPage()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.loadPage/) method to load an external page from a file.

Example:

```
$("#loadpage" ).on( "click", function() {
   $.mobile.loadPage( "../templates/about.html");
});
```